# Best way to secure an ftp server

Tags: windows-server-2003, ftp

I have an ftp server using filezilla  server on windows 2003 and it is added as a member server to the domain with a static ip address and the same subnet as the domain controller. I have opened the specific ports on the router to reach the ftp server, I wondered if this was the best way to set this up in terms of security or if I could improve the setup?

I am concerned with the ftp server being breached and people then being able to access the domain controller. I initially planned to have the ftp server standalone on a seperate network but this would end up involving a  software firewall to seperate the networks and seemed like over kill, I am just looking for some general advice from an infrastructure point of view.

Comment: Best way to secure an FTP server: Don't have one.

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could improve the security by replacing it with an SFTP or FTPS server.

FTP is insecure, in that the login details are passed in plain text. You can replace it with a secure protocol, or only use accounts that you honestly don't care if they are broken (like, anonymous-only), or require it be tunneled over IPSec, or limit connections to only known IP addresses (which is pretty poor security, but hey, do what you have to do.)

These are general suggestions and some good practices. "Best way" and "security" really have to take into account what you're securing, what your requirements are, etc. You haven't told us a single one of your requirements or constraints. Add some more details, and you might get a more useful answer.

/edit : You say

> I am concerned with the ftp server being breached and people then being able to access the domain controller.

For this to happen, there would have to be an exploit in the code of filezilla. Since it's (AFAIK) closed source there could be that sort of bug.  [edit - this is incorrect, it's GPL. Doesn't mean there's no bugs in the codez]. However, if the process (or service) is running as LOCAL SYSTEM, then it has absolutely no rights on the domain, so if it were exploited, all they can do is trash the member server that is running Filezilla. Of course, it does give them a beachhead to attempt attacks against your domain, but it doesn't give them the whole picnic basket right away.

Keep in mind, that this can happen with any software, not just FTP. If you allow access from the internet to a machine in your LAN, and there's an exploitable bug in the code, you've got an attacker on your LAN.

If you're really concerned about it, then put it on a non-domain machine in a DMZ. You said it's a lot of work; security generally is.